# T-SQL Divide value across rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, default-value, between, divide

I have the following columns and data in table:

```
PeriodID Days
1        NULL
2        NULL
3        NULL
4        NULL
5        NULL
```

Then I have days that should divide across the rows as follows:

1. If Days < 5 (for example 2) I will have:

   ```
   PeriodID Days
   1        NULL
   2        NULL
   3        NULL
   4        1
   5        1
   ```
2. If days >= 5 and days%5=0 (for example 5) I will have:

   ```
   PeriodID Days
   1        1    
   2        1    
   3        1    
   4        1    
   5        1
   ```
3. If days > 5 and days%5!=0 (for example 12) I will have:

   ```
   PeriodID Days
   1        3    
   2        3    
   3        2    
   4        2    
   5        2
   ```

I am able doing this with loops, and I hope for better solution using some smart technique or T-SQL function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last example i have days. 12/5=2 and 12%2=2, So each period has 2 days and the rest 2 days are populate from the begging (Period1 has 3 and Period2 has 3)

Comment: I'm not getting the logic you are using - why if less than 5 are they allocated first to greater periods (4 and 5) while if greater than 5 for non-multiples of 5 they are allocated first to lesser periods (1 and 2)?

Comment: Well, because I need to have 5 periods each time and this is sample data. In the real situation I am displaying this information in bar chart, and the right bars (the bigger periods) needs to be populated first if there is no data. Anyway, this is not so important, I can move this logic in the code that is rendering the chart. Anyway, everything you have said about the logic, you have understand correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
DECLARE @numDays int
SET @numDays = 12

UPDATE someTable
SET Days = CASE WHEN @numDays < 5 
                  THEN CASE WHEN @numDays >= 6 - PeriodId THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
                ELSE FLOOR((@numDays + 5 - PeriodId) / 5)
           END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's working will all my cases. Also, the way you are using the FLOOR function for solving the issue is very clever.

Comment: +1 very clever, floor is not necessary though, not on sql server

Comment: @t-clausen.dk correct, it's not necessary but much more clear as to the intent :)